# Need to create a customized JSON in SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I need to return a JSON Data from SQL. I have used `JSON PATH, AUTO, JSON_QUERY()` to achieve those. My final output may look like below.

```
{ "A": [{ "01": {ID:1,Name:,'Test' }, "02" : { ID:2,Name:,'Test2' } "03" :{ ID:3,Name:,'Test3'} ] "B": 
[{ "01": {ID:4,Name:,'Test4' }, "02" : { ID:5,Name:,'Test5' } "03" :{ ID:3,Name:,'Test3'} ]
"C"....... }]
```

How to achieve this in SQL using `FOR JSON PATH`?.

Comment: Can you add the raw code and any queries that you've tried?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What's your actual *input*, as in, table structures? Producing literally this output is of course trivial -- you can just copy-paste that in an `NVARCHAR` -- but I suspect it needs to vary based on your input.

Comment: Actually the above json which I pasted is just a format. The output is expected to come like this. SQL is not returning the above json. I need to query in a way to get that json. @JeroenMostert

Comment: The output as you've got it now is not even valid JSON (property names not quoted, singe quotes instead of double quotes, missing commas, missing values), so it would be quite hard to produce it. And if it's "just a format", you still need to explain what data you are going to use to produce that. What is "A"? What is "01"? Are the "ID" and "Name" table columns?

Comment: OK start from the beginning. Please show us your tables and sample data (as text) and please show us the code you have so far.